# How to limit width of a ListTile

Tags: flutter

I'm using ListTiles in a horizontal menu. However each ListTile seems to be the same width, which is quite wide. I only want the width to be wide enough for the text and a small amount of padding. Can this be done?

Comment: ListTiles cant be resized, you can make your custom `ListTile`, else wrap with other widgets like `center`, `row` etc

Comment: Put screenshots of what you have done? OR Code too.

Comment: If I understand your question, you can look ``Expanded`` widget

Comment: @Yeasin: I did suspect it wasn't possible, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Comment: yes , but we can manipulate that